# Consistency of a Measure and Using Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem in the Context of Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm currently working through a proof that discusses the relationship between Lévy processes in law and infinitely divisible distributions, presented in [Sato](https://www.cambridge.org/br/universitypress/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/levy-processes-and-infinitely-divisible-distributions?format=HB&isbn=9780521553025). The proof involves defining a measure (7.4), and then claims that the family {$\mu_{t_0,\cdots,t_n}$} is consistent, defined in Sato as
$$
\mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_n}(B_{1} \times \cdots \times B_{n}) = \mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_{k-1},t_{k+1},\ldots,t_n}(B_{1} \times \cdots \times B_{k-1} \times B_{k+1} \times \cdots \times B_{n}),
$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and where $B_1,\dots, B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $B_k = \mathbb{R}^d$.
This point is not immediately clear to me, and I'm struggling to understand why the consistency holds true. I don't think I fully understand the integral expression of the measure and how to manipulate it to prove consistency.

I attempted to prove it for a simpler case for a fixed small $n$, using equation (7.1) and the definition of convolution of measures as follows:
\begin{equation}
\mu * \nu (B) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 1_B(x + y) d\mu(x)d\nu(y).
\end{equation}

However, I couldn't make sense of how this applies or proves the consistency.

[image]